# Using Node.jsHow do I filter a JSON document from a seperate config file that has an array or object containing the keys to keep?

Tags: node.js, json, config

Let’s say I have a JSON object like this:

```
{“first”:”first value”,
“second”:”second value”,
“third”:”third value”}
```

I have a config file that is like this as an example:

```
{“filterList”:
{“first”: true,
“second”: false,
“third”: true}}
```

I want to use the config list to filter out the keys that are false and keep the keys that true. The config structure is just an example and I can change it if there is a better solution.
How do I go about this in best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can load the configFile using require("filename") or JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')), then use it to filter the object using Object.entries and Array.reduce, like so:

```js
let configFile = 
{
    "filterList": {
        "first": true,
        "second": false,
        "third": true
    }
}

const originalObj = 
{
    "first": "first value",
    "second": "second value",
    "third": "third value"
}

console.log({ originalObj });

const filteredObj = Object.entries(originalObj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { 
    if (configFile.filterList[key]) {
        acc[key] = value;
    }
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log("Using Array.reduce:", { filteredObj } );
```

And using @RickNs excellent suggestion (Object.fromEntries):

```js
let configFile = 
{
    "filterList": {
        "first": true,
        "second": false,
        "third": true
    }
}

const originalObj = 
{
    "first": "first value",
    "second": "second value",
    "third": "third value"
}

console.log({ originalObj });

const filteredEntries = Object.entries(originalObj).filter(([key, value]) => configFile.filterList[key])
const filteredObj = Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries)

console.log("Using Object.fromEntries:", { filteredObj } );
```

Comment: An alternative to `.reduce` is to use `.filter`: `const filtered = Object.entries(originalObj).filter( ([key]) => configFile.filterList[key] )` then do `Object.fromEntries(filtered)` (a matter of taste, really).

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent suggestion @RickN.. Object.fromEntries is present since Node 12.0 I think.

Comment: The object.reduce worked perfectly. Although I am unsure as to what is happening under the hood. I will also try the other method to see what I prefer and work out what is actually happening.